# Divisão não gera o resultado esperado

Tags: c, matemática, tipagem

Quando eu faço a divisão de `mul / total_filhos_mul` a variável `mul` é zerada, se eu não fizer está divisão ela fica com o valor correto.

O que pode estar ocorrendo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int hab,i=0,hom=0,mul,sal_menor=0,total_filhos_mul,sem_filhos=0,soma_sal=0;
    char sexo;
    printf("informe o numero de habitantes:\n");
    scanf("%d",&hab);

    mul =0;
    hom =0;

    int sal[hab];
    int filhos_mul[hab];

    for(i = 0; i < hab; i++){
        printf("\ninforme o valor do salario:");
        scanf("%d", &sal[i]);
        printf("\nquantidade de filhos:");
        scanf("%d", &sem_filhos);
        if(sal[hab] <= 600 && sem_filhos == 0)
            sal_menor=sal_menor + 1;

            printf("\ninforme o sexo (F/M):");
            scanf("%s", &sexo);
            if(sexo == 'm')
                hom = hom + 1;

                if(sexo == 'f'){
                    mul=mul + 1;
                    printf("\nquantidade de filhos:");
                    scanf("%d", &filhos_mul[i]);
                }

                total_filhos_mul = total_filhos_mul + filhos_mul[i];
                soma_sal = soma_sal + sal[i];

                printf("\n\n\n-------#########################################-------\n\n\n");

    }

    int maior, menor;
    maior = sal[0]; 
    menor = sal[0];

    for (i = 0; i < hab; ++i) {
        if (sal[i] > maior){
            maior = sal[i];
        }
        if (sal[i] < menor){
            menor = sal[i];
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d mulheres", mul/*total_filhos_mul*/);
    printf("\n%d total de filhos", total_filhos_mul);

    float media_sal;
    media_sal = hab / soma_sal;
    printf("\nA media do salario da populacao e: %.2f\n", media_sal);

    float media_filhos;
    media_filhos = mul / total_filhos_mul;
    printf("\nA media de filhos das mulheres e: %.2f\n", media_filhos);

    printf("\nO maior salario e: %d\n", maior);
    printf("\nO menor salario e: %d\n", menor);
}
```

Comment: Bom dia eu editei sua pergunta para tentar deixar ela um pouco mais legível, contudo tem alguma partes no seu código que eu não consegui edentar perfeitamente pela falta do `{}` se puder revisar.

Comment: Você inicia `mul =0;`... se não houver nenhuma mulher, continuará com 0. Como você sabe que `mul` continua 0 se você não imprime este valor após a realização do cálculo (`media_filhos = mul / total_filhos_mul;`)?

Comment: Já inicializei mul =0, mas ela é zerada se eu faço a divisão por total_filhos_mul, quando eu não faço essa divisão e dou um printf nessa variável ela retorna com a valor correto.

Comment: Eu imprimo este valor logo no final do código @Dalton  printf("\nA media de filhos das mulheres e: %.2f\n", media_filhos);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É um problema de tipagem. As duas variáveis da divisão são inteiras, então o resultado é um inteiro. Precisa fazer um *cast* para `float` antes de fazer a divisão.

Foi duro chegar nesta conclusão por que o código é pouco legível. Declare variáveis perto de onde ela será usada.

Eu ia até melhorar o código, mas vi que tem outros problemas, ou pelo menos não está claro o que o algoritmo precisa fazer e uma mudança pode resultar em mais coisa errada.